# Saving an item in the drafts folder also creates a blank outbox item

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, .net-4.0, outlook-2013

I have a C# console app that dynamically creates a bunch of emails and saves them to the Drafts folder in Outlook 2013. However, I've run into an issue where the items I create are not only created in the Drafts folder, but a blank item is also created in the Outbox folder (one blank Outbox item is created for every filled in Drafts item).

For comparison, when I try to create a draft email using the UI, it works as intended. I create a new email, click Save, and the item only appears in the Drafts folder. When I try to do it programmatically, the Outbox items are created.

Here's the C# code I'm using to create the emails:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
Outlook.Account smtpAddress = null;
Outlook.MAPIFolder draftsFolder = null;

ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
draftsFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);

Outlook.MailItem email = draftsFolder.Items.Add("IPM.NOTE");
email.Subject = "Test";
email.HTMLBody = "Test draft email";
email.Recipients.Add(smtpAddress.SmtpAddress);
email.Recipients.ResolveAll();
email.UnRead = True;
email.Save();
```

I also tried this variation:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
Outlook.Account smtpAddress = null;
Outlook.MAPIFolder draftsFolder = null;

ns = app.Session;
ns.Logon(Profile:"", Password:Type.Missing, ShowDialog:Type.Missing, NewSession:true);
draftsFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts) As Outlook.Folder;

Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)draftsFolder.Items.Add("IPM.NOTE");
email.Subject = "Test";
email.HTMLBody = "Test draft email";
email.Recipients.Add(smtpAddress.SmtpAddress);
email.Recipients.ResolveAll();
email.UnRead = True;
email.Save();
```

To troubleshoot, I created the following VBA code in an Outlook module to test out similar code to the above:

```
Sub SaveEmailToDraftFolder()
    Dim app As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.nameSpace
    Dim fd As Outlook.folder
    Dim em As Outlook.MailItem

    Set app = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fd = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

    Set em = fd.Items.Add("IPM.NOTE")

    With em
        .Subject = "Test VBA"
        .HTMLBody = "This is a test."
        .Recipients.Add (smtpAddress)  'smtpAddress is just a placeholder for a real email address
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
        .UnRead = True
        .Save
    End With
End Sub
```

The VBA code, when run, does the same thing as the C# code. It creates a completed email in the Drafts folder, but also creates a blank item in the Outbox.

For reference, I have two Outlook profiles and have the application prompt me for the one to use when I open Outlook. However, I've tested running both the console app and the VBA code if I change the setting to always use my default profile ("Outlook"), and it still creates a blank Outbox item every time it creates a completed Drafts item.

Has anyone experienced this issue and, if so, how did you resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `save` it before you mark it `.UnRead = True`

VBA Code

```
With em
    .Subject = "Test VBA"
    .HTMLBody = "This is a test."
    .Recipients.Add ("smtpAddress")  'smtpAddress is placeholder for a real email address
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .Save
    .UnRead = True
End With
```

Comment: Superb.. This post saved a lot of time.Thanks a lot Om3r and user2063351.