# How to save email as draft?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have 20+ emails created by Excel VBA code.

I want to save these as draft.

```vb
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = email_from
    .To = email_to
    .CC = email_cc
    .BCC = email_bcc
    .subject = subject
    .HTMLBody = "Dear All,<br /> <br/>Please find below today's MIS. <br/>" & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Attachments.Add (Attach_Path)
    .display
End With
```

Comment: How about `OutMail.Save` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36992917/4539709

Answer (score 9):

Should be just a simple case of `Save` and `Close`..

```
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = email_from
    .To = email_to
    .CC = email_cc
    .BCC = email_bcc
    .Subject = Subject
    .HTMLBody = "Dear All,<br /> <br/>Please find below today's MIS. <br/>" & RangetoHTML(Rng)
    .Attachments.Add (Attach_Path)
    .Save
    .Close
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = email_from
    .To = email_to
    .CC = email_cc
    .BCC = email_bcc
    .Subject = Subject
    .HTMLBody = "Dear All,<br /> <br/>Text <br/>" & RangetoHTML(Rng)
    .Attachments.Add (Attach_Path)
    .Close olSave
End With
```